# Setting up async class-based unittests with pytest fixtures

Tags: python, asynchronous, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to set up class-based unittests using pytest and it's fixtures but can't get it working.

The system I'm building is built with FastAPI and Tortoise ORM.

conftest.py

```
from app.main import app
from httpx import AsyncClient

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
async def client():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://test') as c:
        yield c
```

tests.py

```
from tortoise.contrib.test import TestCase

class MyTestcase(TestCase):
    async def test_get_google(self):
        r = await client.get('/dashboard/')
        assert r.status_code == 200
```

I'd like to be able to use the `client` fixture inside the test, but I can't figure out how to include it. I've followed the patterns [here](https://tonybaloney.github.io/posts/async-test-patterns-for-pytest-and-unittest.html) but no luck; the author isn't using async class-based tests.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `TestCase` may be you can try [IsolatedTestCase](https://tortoise.github.io/_modules/tortoise/contrib/test.html#IsolatedTestCase)
and then you can override your `_setUpDB` method and assign request client like this 
`self.client = httpx.AsyncClient(app=FastAPI(), base_url="http://testserver")`.
Then you can get response this way `response = await self.client.get('/dashboard/')` in your tests